# Memory Leak with Redux Toolkit's createListenerMiddleware

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I use Redux Toolkit, and in particular the new listener api, to perform tasks similar to what I could do with Redux-Saga.

Unfortunately, since a few days, I'm stuck with a memory leak and I can't find the cause.

I have reproduced a minimal example of the code that produces this memory leak, link to the example : https://github.com/MrSquaare/rtk-memory-leak

To observe this memory leak :

- I use Chromium, DevTools memory tool
- I trigger a garbage collector
- I make a heap memory snapshot
- I dispatch entity/load (via the UI button)
- I make several heap memory snapshots every 2-3 seconds
- I use the comparison tool, I notice that I have the array allocation size growing infinitely

And after dispatch entity/unload, then make a snapshot heap memory, we can observe that the allocations disappear...

Has anyone observed similar behavior? Or does anyone have an idea of the cause? Thanks!

EDIT 1:

I made an example with only the listener middleware ([`only-middleware` branch](https://github.com/MrSquaare/rtk-memory-leak/tree/only-middleware)), and compared it with different ways of doing :

- With `forkApi.pause` : Important leaks, especially of the generated entities
- Without `forkApi.pause` : I use directly `api.dispatch`, no more leaks of the generated entities, some leaks of other kinds, but maybe normal things (I am not qualified enough to pronounce on this)
- Without `api.dispatch` : I call directly the function that generates an entity, same result as with `api.dispatch`

It seems that the leak is related to `forkApi.pause`, but again I am not qualified enough to know the real cause...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the `promises.forEach`. Every 1000ms, you create a bunch of new promises and schedule things for them. You never wait for the last batch of those promises to finish, so they accumulate.

Replace the `promises.forEach` with a `await Promise.all(promises.map` and see what that does.

---

After reading your solution more closely, I believe you can do this with less problems by sticking more to the reducer and less to the listenerMiddleware.

I would suggest these changes:

```
export const entitySlice = createSlice({
    name: "entity",
    initialState: entityAdapter.getInitialState({ acceptingEntities: false }),
    reducers: {
        upsertOne: (state, action) => {
            entityAdapter.upsertOne(state, action.payload);
        },
        removeAll: (state) => {
            entityAdapter.removeAll(state);
        },
        load(state) { state.acceptingEntities = true },
        unload(state) { state.acceptingEntities = false },
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(getEntity.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            if (!state.acceptingEntities) return;
            const prevEntity = entitySelectors.selectById(state.entity, id);
            entityAdapter.upsertOne(state,
                prevEntity
                    ? mergeEntityData(prevEntity.data, action.payload.data)
                    : action.payload.data
            )
        })
    }
});
```

and

```js
entityMiddleware.startListening({
    actionCreator: api.actions.load,
    effect: async (action, api) => {
        const task = api.fork(async (forkApi) => {
            while (!forkApi.signal.aborted) {
                for (const id of entityIds) {
                    api.dispatch(getEntity(id))
                }
                await api.delay(1000);
            }
        });

        await api.condition(api.actions.unload.match);

        task.cancel();
    },
});
```

Generally:

- logic like calculating a new value belongs into the reducer, not outside. Doing stuff like this outside always has the risk of race conditions and in the reducer you always have all the info available (also, no risk of hogging memory by holding stale value references)
- dispatching another action directly after a thunk will only add more workload - after every reducer, every selector will rerun and your UI might rerender. Just go for an `extraReducer` from the start
- I just added a boolean `acceptingEntities` to indicate if updates should currently take place or not
- this massively reduces complexity in your listener

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply

I'm doing so because I do not want to wait for promises, I want to fetch (here fake data) every N seconds, if I'm waiting for promises to resolve I'll add the resolve time to the global delay;
Nevertheless, i tried to wait for all promises before continuing to see if the problem was actually here, but with the following code I still have memory leaks

```ts
// ...

await Promise.all(promises.map(async (promise) => {
  const res = await promise;

  api.dispatch(entitySlice.actions.upsertOne(res));
}));

// ...
```

Comment: The problem is that if those promises resolve late (or never), the variables referenced in that code will stick around those resolve - especially stuff like the state, which is a full copy of the state "at that time". You might be collecing quite a lot of stale variables that way.

Comment: I added an alternative suggestion how you might go about this

Answer (score 0):

It *may* be related to use of `Promise.race()`: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/17469 .  Filed https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3020 for us to look at this further.

Comment: @MrSquaare could you give this PR a try? https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/3021